# Create default roles and users using SimpleMembership MVC 4 - Code first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I need to create default roles (admin and user) and a default user (my administrator) to my MVC application. I am using code first approach. I am new to MVC and don't know much about migration.

I tried following code, but still my tables (**webpages_Roles** and **UserProfile**) are blank:

```
 protected override void Seed(Outliner.Models.OutlinerDbContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //

            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

            var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider;
            var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider;

            if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
                roles.CreateRole("Admin");

            if (!roles.RoleExists("User"))
                roles.CreateRole("User");

            if (General.IsNull(membership.GetUser("admin", false)))
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateAccount("admin", "password");
            }
        }
```

What is the right approach to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: Did you run `Update-Database` from the Pacakge manager console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set your database initializer?

For example, add this code to your `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax`

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new OutlinerDbInitializer());
```

I presumed that your class for initialization has this signature:

```
public class OutlinerDbInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Outliner.Models.OutlinerDbContext context> {
    ...
}
```

Try looking this example:

http://www.itorian.com/2012/10/entity-frameworks-database-seed-method.html

Comment: thanks .. I have SimpleMembershipInitializer ... and I placed my code there .. now it is working  .. :)